# How to bring errors back into the normal events flow?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

In this example, the `source` `Observable` generates numbers between 0 and 6, and considers 6 as an error. How can I create a `target` `Observable` that brings the errors back to the normal events flow.

I tried this but it stops working when an error occurs.

```js
const { of, interval, throwError } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, map, catchError } = rxjs.operators;

const source = interval(1000).pipe(
    map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)),
    switchMap(result => result < 6 ? of(result) : throwError(result)));
    
const target = source.pipe(catchError(err => of(err)));

target.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to add that `catchError` is given a second argument which represents the **caught observable**. Basically, if you want to re-subscribe to the source when an error occurs, you can also do this:

```js
src$.pipe(
  catchError((err, caught$) => caught$)
).subscribe(/* ... */)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the contract says here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html

> When an Observable does issue an OnCompleted or OnError notification,
>   the Observable may release its resources and terminate, and its
>   observers should not attempt to communicate with it any further.

That means we have to return the `source` `Observable` again after an error occurs, like this:

```js
const { of, interval, concat, throwError } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, map, catchError } = rxjs.operators;

const source = interval(1000).pipe(
        map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)),
        switchMap(result => result < 6 ? of(result) : throwError(result)));

const target = source => source.pipe(catchError(err => concat(of('Error: ' + err), target(source))));

target(source).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```